# Initialise a pointer to two-dimensional array, then to link it with another array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

This is working well:

```
byte (*bufferedPacket)[nbPrioLP][lePrioLP] = &outBuffPacketPrio;
```

But I need to do something like this:

```
byte **bufferedPacket = NULL; // wrong way

if ( _cmd == "prio" ) (*bufferedPacket)[nbPrioLP][lePrioLP] = &outBuffPacketPRIO; 
else (*bufferedPacket)[nbLP][leLP] = &outBuffPacket;
```

This is inside a function, and I want to initialise the buffer with a different size of array.

How should I initialise the pointer?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

This code is inside a function. This function is managing a buffer of packets. I have 2 types of packets: 8 and 30 bytes longs. To optimise the RAM, the number of packets are different (10 and 19 packets).

The 2 buffers (arrays outBuffPacketPRIO, outBuffPacket) are global variable from the main loop. The function have static variables to remember the position of the packets to empty/fill the buffer.

Inside the function, I try to point to 2 buffers to avoid to write 2 identical function, with just a different buffer (outBuffPacketPRIO, outBuffPacket).

I call the function like this:

```
doByteBuffer("regular", 229, "add"); // add byte in the buffer
```

**EDIT 2**

I have this function

```
byte doByteBuffer(String _prio, byte _byte, String _action) {
  static byte posAddBytePrio, posAddPacketPrio, posTakePacketPrio, posAddByteReg, posAddPacketReg, posTakePacketReg;
  static unsigned long timePrio, timeReg;
  if ( _prio == "prio" ) return doBuffer( _action, _prio, &(outBuffPacketPrio[nbPrioLP][0]), &timePrio, &posTakePacketPrio, nbPrioLP, &posAddPacketPrio, lePrioLP, &posAddBytePrio, _byte );
  if ( _prio == "regular" ) return doBuffer( _action, _prio, &(outBuffPacket[nbLP][0]), &timeReg, &posTakePacketReg, nbLP, &posAddPacketReg, leLP, &posAddByteReg, _byte );
}
```

calling this one:

```
byte doBuffer(String _action, String _prio, byte *_buffer, unsigned long *_time, byte *_posTakePacket, byte _nb, byte *_posAddPacket, byte _len, byte *_posAddByte, byte _byte) {
  boolean cond1, cond2, cond3;
  // init
  if ( *_posAddPacket >= _nb ) *_posAddPacket = 0; // cycle counting
  if ( *_posTakePacket >= _nb ) *_posTakePacket = 0; // cycle counting
  // packet overflow
  if ( (_action == "add") || (_action == "end") || (_action == "ack") ) {
    cond1 = ( *_posTakePacket == *_posAddPacket );
    if ( (*_posTakePacket+1) >= _nb ) cond2 = ( *_buffer[0][0] != 0 ); // WRONG WAY
...
}
```

I get this error on the last line of this function:

```
SCD_XBee.ino: In function 'byte doBuffer(String, String, byte*, long unsigned int*, byte*, byte, byte*, byte, byte*, byte)':
SCD_XBee:25: error: invalid types 'unsigned char[int]' for array subscript
```

Do you have an idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Just a FIY, `==` aplied to strings doesn't check their contents, it checks if they point to the same place in memory.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Doesn't this mean that bufferedPacket is a pointer to a 2-d array of bytes?  And you're just assigning it to an object that's already been allocated with the correct size?  So, why do you need a function?</strike>

Ok, so you are putting the byte into one or the other array.  You essentially just do:

```
if ( strncmp( _cmd, "prio", 4 ) )
{
    doAddByte( &(outBuffPacketPRIO[nbPrioLP][0]), lePrioLP, _byte );
    nbPrioLP++;
}
else
{
    doAddByte( &(outBuffPacket[nbLP][0]), leLP, _byte );
    nbLP++;
}

void doAddByte( byte* buffer, int buflen, byte _b )
{
    // buffer is now the pointer to the packet you want to add
    // and buflen is the max size of the packet
    buffer[3] = _b;
}
```

Comment: This code is inside a function. This function is managing a buffer of packets. I have 2 types of packets: 8 and 30 bytes longs. To optimise the RAM, the maximum number of packets stored are different (10 and 19 packets).

The 2 buffers (arrays outBuffPacketPRIO, outBuffPacket) are global variable from the main loop. The function have static variables to remember the position of the packets to empty/fill the buffer.

Inside the function, I try to point to 2 buffers to avoid to write 2 identical function with a different buffer (outBuffPacketPRIO, outBuffPacket).

Comment: I call the function like this:

    doByteBuffer("regular", 229, "add"); (eq. add byte in the buffer)

With your suggestion, I get this error:

    SCD_XBee:20: error: cannot convert 'byte (*)[10][8]' to 'byte**' in assignment
    SCD_XBee:30: error: cannot convert 'byte (*)[19][30]' to 'byte**' in assignment
    SCD_XBee:54: error: invalid type argument of 'unary *'
    SCD_XBee:55: error: invalid type argument of 'unary *'

Comment: It seems like you're making this more complex than it needs to be.  Is the declaration for your global buffer "byte outBuffPacket[19][30]"?

Comment: Yes it is my global declaration.

Comment: Ok, I've changed the answer to be what you really want to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot, John. I think I'm almost arrived. Still block. Have a look, I have edited my post (EDIT 2)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **JonS**, You gave me the idea. Then I saw this: "Sometimes you need to write a function to accept a 2 dimensional array where the width is not known until run time. In this case, you can pass a pointer to the [0][0] element and also pass the two dimensions, and then use pointer arithmetic to get the right element, for example: x[i * width + j]"

Si I solved it like this:

```
byte doByteBuffer(String _prio, byte _byte, String _action) {
  static byte posAddBytePrio, posAddPacketPrio, posTakePacketPrio, posAddByteReg, posAddPacketReg, posTakePacketReg;
  static unsigned long timePrio, timeReg;
  if ( _prio == "prio" ) return doBuffer( _action, _prio, &outBuffPacketPrio[0][0], &timePrio, &posTakePacketPrio, nbPrioLP, &posAddPacketPrio, lePrioLP, &posAddBytePrio, _byte );
  if ( _prio == "regular" ) return doBuffer( _action, _prio, &outBuffPacket[0][0], &timeReg, &posTakePacketReg, nbLP, &posAddPacketReg, leLP, &posAddByteReg, _byte );
}

byte doBuffer(String _action, String _prio, byte *_buffer, unsigned long *_time, byte *_posTakePacket, byte _nb, byte *_posAddPacket, byte _len, byte *_posAddByte, byte _byte) {
  boolean cond1, cond2, cond3;
  // init
  if ( *_posAddPacket >= _nb ) *_posAddPacket = 0; // cycle counting
  if ( *_posTakePacket >= _nb ) *_posTakePacket = 0; // cycle counting
  // packet overflow
  if ( (_action == "add") || (_action == "end") || (_action == "ack") ) {
    cond1 = ( *_posTakePacket == *_posAddPacket );
    if ( ( (*_posTakePacket) + 1 ) >= _nb ) cond2 = ( _buffer[0 * _len + 0] != 0 ); // _buffer[0][0]
    else cond2 = ( _buffer[ ((*_posTakePacket)+1)*_len + 0 ] != 0 ); // _buffer[posTakePacket+1][0]
    if ( cond1 && cond2 ) {
....
```